# Using TanStack Query with Child

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

i want to use query inside child object of Category but im gettin this error.

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error:

> QueryClientProvider to set one No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

pages/category/[pid].js

```
  15 |      heading: pid,
  16 |  };
> 17 |  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(["movieImage"], get);
     |                                      ^
  18 |  if (isLoading) {
  19 |      return <div>Loading...</div>;
  20 |  }
```

index.js

```
import Banner from '../components/Banner';
import Category from '../components/Category';
import LiveAuction from '../components/LiveAuction';
import TopCollectors from '../components/TopCollectors';
import TrendingNow from '../components/TrendingNow';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";
import {
        QueryClient,
        QueryClientProvider,
} from "react-query";
import { Fragment } from 'react';
 
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const Home = () => {

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {" "}
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} contextSharing={true}>
                <Banner />
                <Category />
                <LiveAuction />
                <TopCollectors />
                <TrendingNow />
                <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={true} />
            </QueryClientProvider>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Home
```

some part of pages/category/[pid].js

```
const { pid } = router.query;
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(["movieImage"], getGenres);
if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

tried to change ReactQueryDevtools position
added Fragment
added contextSharing={true} to QueryClientProvider

Comment: is this a next js setup? if so, please include this in the question, as it matters! Judging from `pages/category/[pid].js`, it could be.

Comment: i forgot to add, sorry

Comment: Setting up the `QueryClientProvider` in your Home page will not make it available for your Category page. You should move the `QueryClientProvider` to the `_app` so it's available for all routes, not just `/pages/index.js`.

Comment: Thanks, working well.
is there any way to use this method with vanilla react.js ?
@juliomalves

Comment: Some logic applies, make sure the provider is setup in `App` and wraps all the components that need it.